# match against previous entries in column, copy the rest of data in the row

Tags: excel, vba, copy, paste

I am trying to make a vba code that will allow quicker entry of possible repeated data.  In my example, I am trying to get the entries in the H column to check if that stock number has already been entered.  If so, copy the data from column I - column M of the matched row to column I - column M of the blank "new entry" row.

Here is one of my attempts at the code

```
    Private Sub finddata()
    Dim stock As Integer
    Dim finalrow As Integer
    Dim i As Integer

    finalrow = Sheet1.Range("H50").End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 2 To finalrow
    stock = Sheet1.Cells(i, 8).Value
    If Cells(i, 8) = stock Then
    Range(Cells(i, 9), Cells(i, 13)).Copy
    Range("I50").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    End If
    Next i

    End Sub
```

[image]

Any advice would be awesome, I cannot use vlookup directly in excel,the cells need to remain empty so data can be input if no match was found.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Matt.

I've been playing with your macro and a dummy dataset similar to yours.

I've made a few modifications to your code that allowed me to get the result you're looking for:

```
Private Sub finddata()
'Dim stock As Integer
Dim finalrow As Integer
Dim i As Integer


'Modified:
finalrow = Sheet1.Range("H1").End(xlDown).Row
For i = 2 To finalrow - 1
    For j = 3 To finalrow
        stock = Sheet1.Cells(j, 8).Value
        If Cells(i, 8) = stock Then
            Range(Cells(i, 9), Cells(i, 13)).Copy
            'Modified line:
            Sheet1.Range("I" & j & ":M" & j).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        End If
    Next j
Next i
Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```

As you can see, first of all I removed the Dim declaration of the stock variable. It was raising an error when overwriting the value.

Second of all, instead of searching upwards from the bottom of the table, I search from H1 all the way to the last used row, for optimization.

Most important, I've nested another for inside your for, checking every other stock number on the column.

Then, I checked the last line inside the If block. I'm not really sure what you were trying to do, as I don't fully get that line on your code. But I tried with my method and it worked.

The result was: **Every stock number that had a match in a previous row will have the same values on columns I through M on that row**

Before executing macro:
[image: Before executing macro]

After executing:
[image: After executing]

I'm not sure if that's *exactly* what you're aiming for, but it's a start.

I'm sure this Macro will have to be implemented on a listener or button for easier use.

Hope it helps.